# ffmpeg conversion - keep audio bitrate

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg to extract the audio from different video formats (flv, mp4) and convert it to mp3.

```
%~dp0ffmpeg.exe -i %1 -ar 44100 -ac 2 -ab 128k "%~dpn1.mp3"
```

This works just fine. However, in my input files, the audio bitrate varies, and I want to adjust the output bitrate accordingly. Even by extensive Google searching, I didn't find any hint how to just keep the original bitrate.

What I would need would be something like:

```
-ab copy
```

Which, of course, does not work.

Is there anything that will work?

P.S: As you might have figured from the formatting above, I'm using a windows batch file. There would be the hack to use *%~dp0ffmpeg.exe -i*, get the audio bitrate by grep and insert it in the command line. I just think there **has** to be an easier and more elegant way.

Comment: Copying the bitrate is not usually a good idea. Not all encoders are equal, and can you trust the person who encoded your input to know what they were doing? Also, this question is more suitable for superuser.com. I believe you can flag your question and request it to be moved if you feel like doing that.

Comment: Thanks, that seems reasonable, you really made me think there. So I guess I will just stick to higher quality to minimize quality loss, since the final mp3 size isn't of crucial importance anyway.

Comment: If you don't care about a specific output file size then use `-aq` or `-q:a` (equivalent to `lame -V`) to choose an output quality level and create a VBR output. See [Recommended LAME settings](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=LAME#VBR_.28variable_bitrate.29_settings) for an idea of what value to use (default is 4).

Answer (score 1):

even though the original thread was looking for an answer without grepping anything, nate's script seems to be the most useful post. but it has some limitations, for example not all outputs give you a bitrate grepped, some turnout to give you just the result "default". here's a little more improved version of it.

```sh
#!/bin/env bash
ext=$1
for f in *.${ext}; do
    x=${f%.*} ;
    x=${x% - YouTube}; # I usually download some song covers from YouTube.
    x=$x".mp3";
    bit=`ffmpeg -i "${f}" 2>&1 | grep Audio | awk -F", " '{print $5}' | cut -d' ' -f1`
    if [ -n "$bit" ]; then
        ffmpeg -i "$f" -ab ${bit}k "$x"
    else
        ffmpeg -i "$f" "$x" # this is if we don't have an output from the grep line above, ffmpeg will keep the original quality, that is 192k for 192k
    fi        
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bash script that will take a file extension and extract audio from any file with that extension, and of course maintain the bitrate. I can't claim the credit of the key piece of the code, as that goes to [the gentleman that writes this blog.](http://blog.kdecherf.com/2012/01/14/ffmpeg-converting-m4a-files-to-mp3-with-the-same-bitrate/)

```sh
#!/bin/bash

ext=$1

for file in *.${ext}; do
    tmpfn=${file%.*} ; # get rid of file ext
    tmpfn=$tmpfn".mp3"; # add mp3 file ext
    # next line gets bitrate of audio from video using ffmpeg
    bit=`ffmpeg -i "${file}" 2>&1 | grep Audio | awk -F", " '{print $5}' | cut -d' ' -f1`
    # finally, convert to mp3 using proper bitrate
    ffmpeg -i "$file" -ab ${bit}k "$tmpfn"
done
```

Just run it in the directory where you have the files like so:

```
$bash script.sh flv
```

where flv is the file extension. Hack it to make it do exactly as you wish or process multiple filetypes to your heart's content.

EDIT: Just a quick note for anyone on Ubuntu/debian/etc. Make sure you install the additional codec package or else it won't work, i.e. you must install ffmpeg and the extra libav codec package or you're gonna have a bad time. This should do the trick:

```
sudo apt-get ffmpeg libavcodec-extra-53
```

Answer (score 0):

As LordNeckbeard states, using the same bitrate to encode in different formats isn't necessarily wise. However...

Here is a batch-file solution which captures the input file bitrate and uses that as a parameter for the encoding command line. This approach was hinted at by the original questioner. The `mp3` output file is created in the same folder as the input file.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
REM Usage: scriptname.cmd "full-quoted-path-to-input-file"
REM Adjust FFMPEG_PATH variable value to match the path to your FFMPEG binary

SET FFMPEG_PATH=C:\Program Files\ffmpeg-20170807-1bef008-win64-static\bin
SET INPUT_FILE_FULL_PATH=%1

REM Get input file bitrate
FOR /F "tokens=5 delims==," %%i IN ('""%FFMPEG_PATH%\ffmpeg.exe" -i %INPUT_FILE_FULL_PATH% 2>&1 | find "Audio:""') DO (
    FOR /F "tokens=1 delims==k" %%j IN ('ECHO %%i') DO ( 
        SET BITRATE=%%j
        SET BITRATE=!BITRATE: =!
        ECHO Input file bitrate is !BITRATE! kb/s
    )
)

REM Encode file using previously captured bitrate
"%FFMPEG_PATH%\ffmpeg.exe" -i %INPUT_FILE_FULL_PATH% -ar 44100 -ac 2 -ab !BITRATE!k "%~dpn1.mp3"
```

There is scope for tightening the code up, for example, a check to make sure at least one argument was provided, and that the `BITRATE` is not empty before beginning the encode, but as a rough and ready solution this should do fine.

Answer (score -1):

Current version of ffmpeg (tested 2.1.4) recommends using "-qscale 0" to preserve quality.  This worked for me on my mpeg4 video test file.

Comment: -qscale 0 does not work for audio bitrate as poster has requested

Answer (score -1):

Try this option: `-codec copy` or `-acodec copy` for only audio.
Check this reference http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-specifiers-1

Answer (score -2):

Instead of

```
-ab copy
```

try

```
-sameq


%~dp0ffmpeg.exe -i %1 -sameq "%~dpn1.mp3"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the idea. Unfortunately, I tried that too, and I always end up with 64k.

Comment: Also, http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/Option%20%27-sameq%27%20does%20NOT%20mean%20%27same%20quality%27